# how to display a bitmap on imageview fetched from sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob, android-bitmap

[I am retrieving blob from my sqlite database where column index of the blob images are 9,10,11 and storing them as byte array. Later converting to bitmap and set to an imageview. There is no error  in the code. but imageview is not displaying the image.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpLQl.png)

Comment: is bitmap really retrieving image i.e is bitmap is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this code:
you must load image bytes from cursor and convert it to Bitmap.

```
byte[] imageBytes = getBlob(cursor, "ImageFieldName", null);
if (imageBytes != null)
{
     Bitmap bmp= convertByteArrayToBitmap(imageBytes);
     imageview1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}

private byte[] getBlob(Cursor cursor, String colName, byte[] defaultValue) {
        try {
            int colIndex;
            if (cursor != null && (colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(colName)) > -1
                    && !cursor.isNull(colIndex))
                return cursor.getBlob(colIndex);
            return defaultValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

private Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] bytes) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
```